# C# Set Dictionary<String, Object> Values using Reflection

Tags: c#, winforms, dictionary, reflection, mef

I have the following working code, this open an form from a loaded .dll using assembly

```
Form main = (Form)CommandFacade.IModuleHandler.IHost as Form;
Assembly Assembly = (Assembly)IArticles.Assembly;
Type Type = Assembly.GetType("DAMS.Module.ARTICLES.Articles_Search", true);
Form Articles_Search = (Form)Activator.CreateInstance(Type) as Form;        
Articles_Search.MdiParent = main;
Articles_Search.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
Articles_Search.Show();
```

But i have declared 1 Dictionary (FormBehavior) in this Form and 1 List (HiddenColumns), i need to set values to this dictionary and add items to the List both using reflection.
Normally i use this code but how i can do it using reflection?

```
Articles_Search.FormBehavior["Control"] = "Value";
Articles_Search.HiddenColumns.Add("article_cost");
```

This is the Article_Search Class:

```
public partial class Articles_Search : Form
{
    // Actions Vars
    public List<String> HiddenColumns = new List<String>();
    public Dictionary<String, Object> FormBehavior = new Dictionary<String, Object> { "Control", null } };
}
```

Comment: `HiddenColumns` is not a dictionary? So are you also asking about how to add an element to a list using reflection?

Comment: @MartinLiversage sorry, I need to change the value of this key `Control` in the dictionary `FormBehavior` and Add Items to the `List<String>` `HiddenColumns`, Both using reflection. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The property that you want to set using reflection is named `Item`:

```
var itemPropertyInfo = dictionary.GetType().GetProperty("Item");
```

There is a an overload to the `SetValue` method that accepts the parameter required by the `Item` property:

```
itemPropertyInfo.SetValue(dictionary, value, new[] { key });
```

Using reflection as explained is equivalent to executing the following code:

```
dictionary[key] = value;
```

---

Above is the general answer on how to set values in a dictionary using reflection. To answer your specific question which also involves a list and presumably private fields I provide this code:

```
var formBehaviorFieldInfo = Articles_Search
  .GetType()
  .GetField("FormBehavior", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
var formBehavior = formBehaviorFieldInfo.GetValue(Articles_Search);
var itemPropertyInfo = formBehavior.GetType().GetProperty("Item");
itemPropertyInfo.SetValue(formBehavior, "Control", new[] { "Value" });

var hiddenColumnsFieldInfo = Articles_Search
  .GetType()
  .GetField("HiddenColumns", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
var hiddenColumns = hiddenColumnsFieldInfo.GetValue(Articles_Search);
var addMethodInfo = hiddenColumns.GetType().GetMethod("Add");
addMethodInfo.Invoke(hiddenColumns, new[] { "article_cost" });
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but assuming that the variables `FormBehavior` and `HiddenColumns` are declared inside `Articles_Search` form; how I can access them to change them using reflection. Because I'm accessing the form through reflection also line: `Form Articles_Search = (Form)Activator.CreateInstance(Type) as Form;  `

Comment: @JonathanEdgardo: Access the dictionary and list through the `Articles_Search` form instance. This assumes that the dictionary and list fields are public. Otherwise you need to use reflection to access private fields but you have not mentioned anything about that this is a problem in your question.

Comment: I appreciate your patience, Yes if you see i am accesing to the form `Articles_Search` using Assembly because is stored in a .dll `Type Type = Assembly.GetType("DAMS.Module.ARTICLES.Articles_Search", true);` but my real problem is for Modify the variables (Dictionary and List) inside the instantiated form.

Comment: Thank you is exactly what I needed to do i only change the `BindingFlags.NonPublic` to `BindingFlags.Public`.

Comment: @JonathanEdgardo: If the fields are public you do not have to use the overload that uses `BindingFlags` because the default is `BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public`. That the fields were private was my assumption.

Comment: The both variables are public in the `Articles_Search` Form, one question more can I Add multiple items to the list `HiddenColumns` with a single line?  `addMethodInfo.Invoke(hiddenColumns, new[] { "article_cost" });`

Comment: What if the dictionary were to contain object instances instead of simple values? How would you modify the value property of each of these objects contained in the dictionary using reflection? Thanks

Comment: @progLearner My answer is not specific to _value types_ (as opposed to _reference types_). You have to use the `PropertyInfo` as described. The type of `value` has to match the type of the values in the dictionary so if the dictionary has type `Dictionary<int, Customer>` then `value` should be a `Customer` _object instance_.

Answer (score 0):

The following answer isn't right in this case. I missed that the assembly isn't referenced at compile time.

---

<del>I don't understand why you need reflection at all. You have already an instance of the desired class, so you can access public fields and properties directly. But you aren't "seeing" this fields or properties because your variable is of type `Form`. Try this:</del>

```
Form main = (Form)CommandFacade.IModuleHandler.IHost;
Assembly Assembly = (Assembly)IArticles.Assembly;
Type Type = Assembly.GetType("DAMS.Module.ARTICLES.Articles_Search", true);
Articles_Search searchForm = (Articles_Search)Activator.CreateInstance(Type);        
searchForm.MdiParent = main;
searchForm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
searchForm.FormBehavior["Control"] = "Value";
searchForm.HiddenColumns.Add("article_cost");
searchForm.Show();
```

Sidenote: You don't need the `as` operator if you are already using a cast operator.

Comment: I assume that the assembly with the form is not referenced at compile time so reflection is required to both create and also access and use the form.